# Why this regex in javascript returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, regex

im trying to split a string when i found a ';' and an 'int'
my input is:

```
var codigo="int a;float b,c;c=a*b;"
```

the regex that im trying to use is:

```
codigo=codigo.split(/(\b;)|(\bint)/)
```

and my output is:

```
["", undefined, "int", " a", ";", undefined, "float b,c", ";", undefined, "c=a*b", ";", undefined, ""]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is because you have two capture groups, JavaScript has to leave two places in the output array for matches. However, only one of those capture groups ever matches because of the way your RegEx is written. I think if you combine the capture groups into a single capture group, the `undefined` s should go away:

```
codigo=codigo.split(/(\b;|\bint)/)
```

Comment: thank you so much that solve my problem :D

Comment: You don't need the non-capturing groups.

Comment: @krisz I didn't think so but I wasn't sure. I'll remove them because it makes it simpler.

Comment: oh that also works too